# Castle Windsor 5.0 PerWebRequest Lifestyle

Tags: asp.net

I recently upgraded and I am seeing errors when installing components from the web.config where the lifestyle is PerWebReqest...if I specify the lifestyle in affluent api, all works fine.  Has anybody had any issues using PerWebRequest in XML configuration either in the webconfig or separate file?

Comment: Please post your errors and explain what you've already tried to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue; when assigning the PerWebRequest lifestyle via the fluent configuration API everything works fine but when I register a component with this lifestyle via my castle.config it throws up:

> Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.ConverterException
>   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=Could not convert from 'perwebrequest' to Castle.Core.LifestyleType.
>    Source=Castle.Windsor
>   ...
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>   ArgumentException: Requested value 'perwebrequest' was not found.

This is with the following configuration (class names omitted):
`<component id="myController" lifestyle="perwebrequest" service="..." type="...">`

My workaround for the moment is to use 'transient' which is less than ideal...